# which version of rails should I use for a new project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been working with rails 2.3.5. I am gonna start a new project on rails. Should i continue using the earlier version or should i hop on to rails > 3 ? If so which is the more stable version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to use rails 3.0.x version as these days lot of new plugins(like [active_reload](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload)) are targeted only for 3.x version.

3.1.x have lot of cool features(like asset pipeline, saas integration, coffescript integration, etc), but its still a release candidate and I faced some issues while using it. I guess we have to wait for the stable 3.1.x release.

I have been using 3.0.7 for a while and found it to be very stable.
3.0.10 is recently released and you can easily upgrade to it from 3.0.7 any time you want in the future.

If you are stuck to 2.x version you will be missing cool features like mentioned here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/5-awesome-new-rails-3-features/

Answer (score 2):

For a new project, I would use Rails 3.1 or for a bit more stability, 3.0.7. There are some noticeable differences compared to 2.3, but it will be supported for longer and most development of new gems and documentation are being written for Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely NOT use 2.3 and earlier.

The Rails framework is improving at a steady pace and if there is a downside to that is that it can be a pain to upgrade from version to version, especially as regards to major version changes which introduce tons of backward incompatibilities.

Why then would you want to put yourself in the hole at the get go.

Another issue is how ready and mature is the ecosystem (ruby, popular gem packages, etc.). This leads you to consider whether you should start with 3.0.10 or 3.1 release candidate.

It turns out the great majority of gems working with Rails 3.0 is also working fine with Rails 3.1.

The little downside is that 3.1 is still in release candidate status but it's all but ready for final release and that should come within a matter of days or maximum a couple weeks (as of today Aug. 25, '11).

I would strongly recommend you start all new apps with 3.1. That's what I'm doing.